# IGDB API v4 searching for a game

Tags: c#, api, rest, oauth, wrapper

Hey all the last time I used IGDB was when it was in version 3 and it was easy to search for a game depending on the platform chosen:

```
    string url = "https://api-v3.igdb.com/games/?search=" + gameNameHere + 
                 "&fields=name,genres,involved_companies,first_release_date,cover";
    HttpWebRequest gameRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
```

However, this version 4 is quite compilated since they tie in Twitch Oauth for some reason in order to call the API.

Besides the Oauth issue I am unable to find a simple search for a game using the [IGDB-DOTNET](https://github.com/kamranayub/igdb-dotnet) wrapper for V4...

[image]

Now for this wrapper I start out (like it says on the website) with the following:

```
var igdb = new IGDBClient(
  // Found in Twitch Developer portal for your app
  Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("IGDB_CLIENT_ID"),
  Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("IGDB_CLIENT_SECRET")
);
```

I place both my Client ID and Secret into the proper spots above. Ok, easy enough.

But now it continues to this - calling it "simple":

```
// Simple fields
var games = await igdb.QueryAsync<Game>(IGDBClient.Endpoints.Games, 
                       query: "fields id,name; where id = 4;");
var game = games.First();
game.Id; // 4
game.Name; // Thief
```

So where did this Thief game ID of 4 come from? How do I search for the game "Thief" and get that ID in order to call the above to get the needed name, cover, artwork, etc...?

The other 3 examples below that also do not show how to search for a game.

So is this below what its looking for me to do in order to search?

```
 var games = await igdb.QueryAsync<Game>(IGDBClient.Endpoints.Games, 
                        query: "search \"Thief\"; fields id,name,cover;");
```

If not then how does one do that for V4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right,

```
var r = await IGDBClient.QueryAsync<Game>(IGDBClient.Endpoints.Games,
                $"search \"{query}\"; fields  id, name,first_release_date,total_rating,summary,cover.*;");
```

where query = "Thief";